# error during production build with gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I use gitlab to do continuous integration (I'm on windows).

When I push my react project I get an error:

> Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true. Most CI
> servers set it automatically.

I tried to:

- add an environment variable CI = false or CI = "" in gitlab environnement variable.
- add variables CI = false or CI = "" in gitlab-ci.yml
- add environment = ["CI="] in config.toml
- add environment variable in windows directly CI -> ""

but still got the error.

How to do please?

**Update 2022-10-20 10:03**

I'm building on a remote server

package.json

```
scripts": {
"startapp": "lerna run start --scope=app",
"startpdf": "lerna run start --scope=pdfserver",
"start": "lerna run start",
"bootstrap": "npx lerna bootstrap --hoist",
"build": "lerna run build",
"buildapp": "lerna run build --scope=app",
"buildpdf": "lerna run build --scope=pdfserver",
"serveapp": "lerna run serve",
"publish": "npm run bootstrap && npm run build && npm run serveapp"
```

}

gitlab-ci.yml

```
    stages:
    - build

buildTest:
    stage: build
    tags:
        - app-test
    script:
        - cp -r -fo "packages\app\.env.test" "packages\app\.env"
        - npm run bootstrap
        - npm run build
        - npm run startpdf
    only:
        - dev
```

config.toml

```
    [[runners]]
  name = "app-test"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  id = xxx
  token = "xxx"
  token_obtained_at = xxx
  token_expires_at = xxx
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To the package.json add following

```
"scripts" : {
    "build" : "CI=false && react-scripts build"
}
```

I supose you should already have that build in scripts. just add CI=false

Comment: it does not work. The error tells me that the command is not recognized..
-> "build": "CI=false && lerna run build",

Comment: How does you gitlab-ci.yml and package.json look like? Where are you building your project? On your local machine or remote server? Do you have gitlab runner set?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works.

I use lerna and craco and I added in the package.json on the build command "set CI=false&&".

```
"build": "set CI=false&&lerna run build",
```

it works